# What are LCD subpixels made of?

Tags: lcd, light, color

Just curious. I don't really need to know this level of granular detail for my job (AV technician) but in courses/articles about color LCD displays they explain everything... except what the red, green, and blue subpixels are made of.

Like with plasma and cathode ray displays, I understand that the red/green/blue colors are created using electrically excited phosphors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LCD "effect" is using a signal to make a subpixel either transparent so that the backlight can shine through or opaque so that it can't. During manufacturing, a very precisely aligned color filter (red, green, or blue) is created in front of each subpixel so that is what the color will be when the liquid crystal behind it lets the white backlight shine through. The color filter itself is a pigment/dye, probably proprietary.

Comment: Thank you for the information! So the level of transparency -- due to the liquid crystal chemistry -- is what creates the different levels of R, G, and B?

Comment: It also means that the majority of the light from the white backlight is lost in the filters. The transmissivity of the LCD + filter is usually in the region of 5%. The backlights are blinding to look at directly.

Comment: The level of transparency is adjusted by the voltage applied to the subpixel.